# How do I select apache2 in phpmyadmin configuration?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

I was installing apache2, mysql and phpmyadmin on my linux for a school project.
When installing phpmyadmin i failed to select apache2 in the configuration (i pressed Enter instead of Spacebar). Now i can't switch it. I tried reinstalling phpmyadmin but it doesn't ask me to select apache2 anymore. I also messed with the databases in mysql for a bit but nothing worked.
Does anyone know a way to get the select screen while installing phpmyadmin again?

Comment: What OS you are using? us linux if so, which distro?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` in terminal this will reconfigure phpmyadmin again and it will ask you to enter the new config, also you can use `sudo apt purge phpmyadmin` to remove phpmyadmin completely, but **not sure about the later since it may remove MySQL along with**